# Model of homotopy type theory where propositional & judgmental equality coincide for closed terms

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, homotopy-type-theory

In intensional Martin-Löf type theory we can prove the metatheorem that two closed terms are propositionally equal iff they are judgmentally equal.

Is there a non-empty model of homotopy type theory where this metatheorem holds?

Comment: You have many basic questions about homotopy type theory and type theory in general, which I think might be answered more quickly at the [HoTT Zulip](https://hott.zulipchat.com/). Are you a member there? I am *not* saying that you shouldn't be asking the questions here, but over there you have dozens of people doing HoTT, whereas here you will quickly exhaust the energy of the few HoTT experts who answer HoTT-related questions.

Comment: The boring answer is yes: just start from the syntactic model and quotient it by propositional equality. But perhaps you meant a certain kind of model where equality is easy to decide?

Comment: P. S. You have not accepted any answers so far (clicked on the "check" next to an answer), which makes it unclear as to whether you are generally dissatisfied with our answers, or you just don't know that it's good manners to accept answers that you are happy with.

Comment: @Jesper: How do you know that model is non-trivial?

Comment: What do you mean by non-trivial? If you just mean that not all types are interpreted as the same, that follows easily from soundness of HoTT: just take an empty and a non-empty type (e.g. `0 == 1` and `1 == 1`), and note that they are interpreted differently.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, it's not clear at all what it means to "quotient the syntacting model by propositional equality". Do you have a reference? Why would we even get a model of type theory this way?

Comment: It's not obvious to me how that would work, either, since there are closed terms of the universe where 'propositional' equality is not a proposition in the homotopy sense. For instance, there are multiple distinct paths between each of $2 + 2$, $2 × 2$ and $2 → 2$. So what does 'quotienting' do in situataions like that?

Comment: @Jesper quotienting the syntax of HoTT by prop equality is the same as adding equality reflection to the syntax, which is inconsistent with univalence, and makes the syntax trivial.

Comment: I don't see how quotienting the *model* by propositional equality is the same as adding equality reflection to the *syntax* of the language. But I do admit I'm a bit out of my depth here, it's possible that I'm wrong.